# Erro no cordova

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Bom dia galera, quando tento complia meu projeto cordova para android de esse mensagem:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.083 secs
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\Users\bruno\MyApp\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\bruno\MyApp\platforms\android\build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

já fiz muta coisa que achei no google, mas nada deu certo, se alguem poder me dar uma luz fico grato...

Comment: Qual seu sistema operacional? Você instalou o SDK do Android?

Comment: windows 10 e o sdk android ta instalado.

Comment: Não é uma resolução muito legal mas... Você pode tentar "cordova build android -- --ant".